# Xcode 7.3 UITableViewController cell not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I try to display a simple cell with one label and an add item button.  I can't get it to display correctly.

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

There is no `add item` button and no correct row.  I have just two items in coredata.

This is my code:

```
   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return items.count
    }

    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        
        let data = items[indexPath.row] as Item
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = data.body
        
        return cell
    }
```

What are the problems?  How can I display `add item` button, correct row count, and customize height of the cell correctly?

Comment: what's the prototype cell style is?

Comment: hi @slxl custom style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets return the correct number of rows unto the table view.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellContent.count
}
```

Next lets get it to output unto the prototype cells.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Also lets call the unto the view controller the following so that it can run properly.

ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

One last thing, your prototype's cell has the same identifier as the one in  your code. In my code I would make sure that the identifier in the prototype cell is "Cell" since I called it in UITableViewCell(...reuseIdentifier: "Cell").
[View picture to see where to add the identifier in your storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2hYi.png)

Comment: i do all this before i posted my question to stackoverflow thanks for response

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I just read your question again, you wanted to add items with a button. Here is a link where you can download my repository. There are a lot of changes you need to make in order to make your code work. https://github.com/andresaguero10/todolistapp